# SImplest way to create 'ca-cert.pem' and 'client-cert.pem' with pure PowerShell

Tags: powershell, openssl

Below, are the manual steps to generate a `ca-cert.pem` and respective `client-cert.pem` using Openssl *(needed for Powershell MySql Connector)*.  I would like to do the same thing automatically in the simplest way possible using **only PowerShell 5**; or, if not possible, with the help of a lightweight PowerShell Module.

```
1. Create key:
openssl genrsa 2048 > ca-key.pem
 
 
2. Create a ca-cert:
openssl req -new -x509 -nodes -days 365000 -key ca-key.pem -out ca-cert.pem
  (enter respective attributes: i.e.,Country Name, State, Locality Name, etc.)


3. Create client certificate request:
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -days 365000 -nodes -keyout client-key.pem -out client-req.pem
  (enter same attributes as above)


4. Clean protected password:
openssl rsa -in client-key.pem -out client-key.pem

 
5. Verify client cert is OK:
openssl x509 -req -in client-req.pem -days 365000 -CA ca-cert.pem -CAkey ca-key.pem -set_serial 01 -out client-cert.pem
```

The closest I can get to doing this is create a self-signed certificate `MyCert.cer` file and export a respective `MyCert.pfx` file using the 3 lines below.  Unfortunately, I don't think I'm even close.  I'm hoping someone with more experience can help me to do this correctly in the simplest way possible.

```PoSH
$cert = New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName "CN=MyCert" -CertStoreLocation "Cert:\CurrentUser\My" -KeyLength 2048 -KeyAlgorithm "RSA" -KeyExportPolicy Exportable 

Export-Certificate -Cert $cert -FilePath "C:\temp\MyCert.cer"

$cert | Export-PfxCertificate -FilePath "C:\temp\MyCert.pfx" -Password (ConvertTo-SecureString -String "password" -AsPlainText -Force)
```

Comment: Well, if you don't mind using a module you can use [PSPKI's Convert-PfxtoPem](https://www.pkisolutions.com/tools/pspki/convert-pfxtopem/) to do it pretty easily. From either a .pfx file, or an installed cert that has an exportable private key.

Comment: Thank you.  If it's currently not possible to do this using just PowerShell 5, I was hoping to do this using a free PS Gallery module or something I can just download from GitHub.